# Understanding coroutineScope

Tags: android, scope, android-context, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Suppose a new coroutine is launched using `viewModelScope` inside a VM and calls a non-suspend function inside a generic repository class

`UserViewModel`

```
viewModelScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.IO) {

                _user.value?.id?.let { id ->
                    val dataSaved = userRepository.setUserData(id, newUser)

                }

}
```

`UserRepository`

```
fun setUserData(id: String, data: User): Boolean {
        return try {
            val saveTask = db.collection(COLLECTION).document(id).set(data)
            Tasks.await(saveTask)
            true
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            false
        }
}
```

1. What's the scope and context in which the `setUserData` is launched?
2. If I add the `suspend` keywork ahead of the `setUserData` function, the `await` method of the `Tasks` will generate a warning saying `Inappropriate blocking method call`. Why?
3. What's the difference with this implementation?

```
suspend fun setUserData(id: String, data: User): Boolean {
        return coroutineScope {
            return@coroutineScope try {
                val saveTask = db.collection(COLLECTION).document(id).set(data)
                Tasks.await(saveTask)
                true
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.e(TAG, "${e.message}")
                false
            }
        }
  }
```

4. Is `coroutineScope` a guarantee that `setUserData` will be launched within the same scope and context of the caller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the scope and context in which the `setUserData` is launched?

Judging from `viewModelScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.IO)`, the context looks this `CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO)`.

> If I add the `suspend` keywork ahead of the `setUserData` function, the `await` method of the `Tasks` will generate a warning saying `Inappropriate blocking method call`. Why?

It is bad practice to block the thread (with `Tasks.await`) in a suspend function, unless the dispatcher supports this. i.e. `Dispatchers.IO`.

IntelliJ/Android Studio isn't smart enough (and probably cannot be) to precisely determine if you're blocking when you're not supposed to. So this could be considered a bug but `setUserData` could be called outside of `Dispatchers.IO`, so IntelliJ has a point here.

> What's the difference with this implementation?

Not much really. It just has some additional overhead that isn't worth it.

As a side note, `coroutineScope` doesn't change the immediate `coroutineContext` like `withContext` does, but it changes the inherited context of launched coroutines.

> Is `coroutineScope` a guarantee that `setUserData` will be launched within the same scope and context of the caller?

You get this guarantee already. You don't need `coroutineScope` to achieve this.

What you probably want here is this.

```
suspend fun setUserData(id: String, data: User): Boolean {
    val saveTask = db.collection(COLLECTION).document(id).set(data)
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            Tasks.await(saveTask)
            true
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(TAG, "${e.message}")
            false
        }
    }
}
```

Then the caller doesn't have to worry about what dispatcher or context to use.

What you should use is this.

```
suspend fun setUserData(id: String, data: User): Boolean {
    val saveTask = db.collection(COLLECTION).document(id).set(data)
    return try {
        saveTask.await() // From `kotlinx-coroutines-play-services`
        true
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e(TAG, "${e.message}")
        false
    }
}
```

This way you don't need to evoke `Dispatchers.IO` and block more threads.

For reference, https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/await.html